# Parse character representation in Jison/Javascript

Tags: javascript, parsing, character, jison

I'm coding a C++ grammar in Jison and I've managed to correctly detect character literals with this regex:

```
\'([^\\\']|\\.)\'  return 'CHAR_LIT'
```

and then add it to the AST like this:

```
| CHAR_LIT
    {$$ = new yy.Ast('CHAR_LIT', [$1])}
```

However, with the input string literal `'\n'` the value of `$1` evaluates to its string representation `"'\\n'"` rather than its actual character value `"\n"`, which is what I want.

Is there any way to tell Jison that I want the character value rather than its representation? 
Otherwise, what is the best way in Javascript to parse a string with a character representation into its corresponding character value, for instance parse `"\\t"` into `"\t"`?

Comment: It's your responsibility to parse character string literals if that's what you want. The program text you are parsing *is* a representation, and there is nothing built-in which would cause jison to guess that you want a transformation of a string value.

Comment: I also guessed that, just wanted to make sure there was absolutely no way it could be done with jison alone, thanks!

Comment: you could write a different jison grammar to just deal with character string literals, but that would probably be overkill; in JS, you can just use regular expressions substitutions (but remember to do all of them just once, to avoid double-decoding).